# System.Property<T> refactored out of Silverlight 4 System.dll?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm in the process of migrating a Silverlight 3 project to Silverlight 4 (plus RIA Services v1.0 RTW and the latest drop of Rx.)  I believe I've dealt with all the dll refactoring and namespace change issues but one.

In the Silverlight 3 project I'm using `System.Project<T>` however `System.Project<T>` is missing from the Silverlight 4 `system.dll`.  Using `Reflector` I see that the following are missing from the Silverlight 4 `system.dll`:

```
IProperty<>
IPropertyGetter<>
IPropertySetter<>
Property
Property<>
PropertyChangedEventArgs<>
PropertyGetter
PropertySetter
```

My question is, where do they live in Silverlight 4?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, the above should read:

"I'm using System.Property<> however System.Property<> is missing from the Silverlight 4 system.dll."

Thanks.